# Custom user federation with keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm new with keycloak and i'm trying to custom the user federation of keycloak I've created a project where at the beginig everything seems to be fine in the option of user the keycloak user federation recognize my adapter the proble is when want to get the user list. Please some help. I thank you in advance

On the same keyclok wildfly server i've created a new connection on the standalone.xml file where the persistence unit is userDs, i also have created the adapter, the provider and factory provider.

User.java

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getUserByUsername", query="select u from User u where u.usuario = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name="getUserByEmail", query="select u from User u where u.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name="getUserCount", query="select count(u) from User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name="getAllUsers", query="select u from User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name="searchForUser", query="select u from User u where " +
            "( lower(u.usuario) like :search or u.email like :search ) order by u.usuario")})
@Table(name="usuario")
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {`
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String id;
private String usuario;
private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private String email;
private String password;
}
```

UserAdapter.java

```
public class UserAdapter extends AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserAdapter.class);
protected User entity;
protected String keycloakId;

public UserAdapter(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, ComponentModel model, User entity) {
    super(session, realm, model);
    this.entity = entity;
    keycloakId = StorageId.keycloakId(model, entity.getId());
}

public String getPassword() {
    return entity.getPassword();
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    entity.setPassword(password);
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return entity.getUsuario();
}

@Override
public void setUsername(String username) {
    entity.setUsuario(username);

}

@Override
public void setEmail(String email) {
    entity.setEmail(email);
}

@Override
public String getEmail() {
    return entity.getEmail();
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return keycloakId;
}

@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return entity.getNombre();
}

@Override
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    entity.setNombre(firstName);
}

@Override
public String getLastName() {
    return entity.getApellidos();
}

@Override
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    entity.setApellidos(lastName);
}
```

UserStorageProviderFactory.java

```
public class UserStorageProviderFactory implements org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory<UserStorageProvider> {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserStorageProviderFactory.class);

@Override
public UserStorageProvider create(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model) {

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        logger.info("URL: " + "java:global/keycloak-jpa/" + UserStorageProvider.class.getSimpleName());
        UserStorageProvider provider = (UserStorageProvider)ctx.lookup("java:global/keycloak-jpa/" + UserStorageProvider.class.getSimpleName());

        provider.setModel(model);
        provider.setSession(session);
        return provider;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "keycloak-jpa-provider";
}

@Override
public String getHelpText() {
    return "JPA Example User Storage Provider";
}

@Override
public void close() {
    logger.info("Closing factory");

}
```

UserStorageProvider.java

```
@Stateful
@Local(UserStorageProvider.class)
public class UserStorageProvider implements org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider,
    UserLookupProvider,
    UserQueryProvider,
    CredentialInputValidator,
    CredentialInputUpdater,
    OnUserCache {`


@PersistenceContext(unitName = "userDS")
protected EntityManager em;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserStorageProvider.class);
public static final String PASSWORD_CACHE_KEY = UserAdapter.class.getName() + ".password";
protected KeycloakSession session;
protected ComponentModel model;

@Remove
@Override
public void close() {
    logger.info("ingresando close");
}

public void preRemove(RealmModel realm) {
    logger.info("ingresando preRemove(RealmModel realm)");
}

public void preRemove(RealmModel realm, GroupModel group) {
    logger.info("ingresando  preRemove(RealmModel realm, GroupModel group)");
}

public void preRemove(RealmModel realm, RoleModel role) {
    logger.info("ingresando preRemove(RealmModel realm, GroupModel group)");
}

public boolean updateCredential(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, CredentialInput credentialInput) {
    logger.info("ingresando updateCredential(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, CredentialInput credentialInput)");
    if (!supportsCredentialType(credentialInput.getType()) || !(credentialInput instanceof UserCredentialModel)) return false;
    UserCredentialModel cred = (UserCredentialModel) credentialInput;
    UserAdapter adapter = getUserAdapter(userModel);
    adapter.setPassword(cred.getValue());

    return true;
}

public void disableCredentialType(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, String s) {
    logger.info("ingresando disableCredentialType(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, String s)");
}

public Set<String> getDisableableCredentialTypes(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel) {
    logger.info("ingresando getDisableableCredentialTypes(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel)");
    return Collections.emptySet();
}

public boolean supportsCredentialType(String credentialType) {
    logger.info("ingresando supportsCredentialType(String credentialType)");
    return CredentialModel.PASSWORD.equals(credentialType);
}

public boolean isConfiguredFor(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, String credentialType) {
    logger.info("ingresando isConfiguredFor(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, String credentialType)");
    return supportsCredentialType(credentialType);
}

public boolean isValid(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, CredentialInput credentialInput) {
    logger.info("ingresando isValid(RealmModel realmModel, UserModel userModel, CredentialInput credentialInput)");
    if (!supportsCredentialType(credentialInput.getType()) || !(credentialInput instanceof UserCredentialModel)) return false;
    UserCredentialModel cred = (UserCredentialModel)credentialInput;
    String password = getPassword(userModel);
    return password != null && password.equals(cred.getValue());
}

public UserModel getUserById(String id, RealmModel realmModel) {
    logger.info("ingresando getUserById: " + id);
    String persistenceId = StorageId.externalId(id);
    User entity = em.find(User.class, persistenceId);
    if (entity == null) {
        logger.info("could not find user by id: " + id);
        return null;
    }
    return new UserAdapter(session, realmModel, model, entity);
}

public UserModel getUserByUsername(String userName, RealmModel realmModel) {
    logger.info("getUserByUsername: " + userName);
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("getUserByUsername", User.class);
    query.setParameter("username", userName);
    List<User> result = query.getResultList();
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        logger.info("could not find username: " + userName);
        return null;
    }

    return new UserAdapter(session, realmModel, model, result.get(0));
}

public UserModel getUserByEmail(String s, RealmModel realmModel) {
    logger.info("ingresando getUserByEmail(String s, RealmModel realmModel)");
    return getUserByUsername(s, realmModel);
}

@Override
public int getUsersCount(RealmModel realmModel) {
    logger.info("ingresando getUsersCount(RealmModel realmModel)");
    Object count = em.createNamedQuery("getUserCount")
            .getSingleResult();
    return ((Number)count).intValue();
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> getUsers(final RealmModel realmModel) {
    logger.info("ingresando getUsers(final RealmModel realmModel)");
    return getUsers(realmModel, -1, -1);
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> getUsers(RealmModel realmModel, int firstResult, int maxResults) {
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("getAllUsers", User.class);
    return getUserModels(realmModel, firstResult, maxResults, query);
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> searchForUser(String search, RealmModel realmModel) {
    return searchForUser(search, realmModel, -1, -1);
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> searchForUser(String search, RealmModel realmModel,  int firstResult, int maxResults) {
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("searchForUser", User.class);
    query.setParameter("search", "%" + search.toLowerCase() + "%");
    return getUserModels(realmModel, firstResult, maxResults, query);
}

private List<UserModel> getUserModels(RealmModel realmModel, int firstResult, int maxResults, TypedQuery<User> query) {
    if (firstResult != -1) {
        query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    }
    if (maxResults != -1) {
        query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    }
    List<User> results = query.getResultList();
    List<UserModel> users = new LinkedList<>();
    for (User entity : results) users.add(new UserAdapter(session, realmModel, model, entity));
    return users;
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> searchForUser(Map<String, String> map, RealmModel realmModel) {
    System.out.println("ingresando searchForUser(Map<String, String> map, RealmModel realmModel)");
    return searchForUser("", realmModel);
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> searchForUser(Map<String, String> map, RealmModel realmModel, int i, int i1) {
    System.out.println("ingresando searchForUser(Map<String, String> map, RealmModel realmModel, int i, int i1)");
    return searchForUser("", realmModel);
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> getGroupMembers(RealmModel realmModel, GroupModel groupModel, int i, int i1) {
    System.out.println("ingresando getGroupMembers(RealmModel realmModel, GroupModel groupModel, int i, int i1)");
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> getGroupMembers(RealmModel realmModel, GroupModel groupModel) {
    System.out.println("ingresando getGroupMembers(RealmModel realmModel, GroupModel groupModel)");
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<UserModel> searchForUserByUserAttribute(String s, String s1, RealmModel realmModel) {
    System.out.println("ingresando searchForUserByUserAttribute(String s, String s1, RealmModel realmModel)");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCache(RealmModel realmModel, CachedUserModel cachedUserModel, UserModel userModel) {
    String password = ((UserAdapter)userModel).getPassword();
    if (password != null) {
        cachedUserModel.getCachedWith().put(PASSWORD_CACHE_KEY, password);
    }
}

public String getPassword(UserModel user) {
    String password = null;
    if (user instanceof CachedUserModel) {
        password = (String)((CachedUserModel)user).getCachedWith().get(PASSWORD_CACHE_KEY);
    } else if (user instanceof UserAdapter) {
        password = ((UserAdapter)user).getPassword();
    }
    return password;
}

public UserAdapter getUserAdapter(UserModel user) {
    UserAdapter adapter = null;
    if (user instanceof CachedUserModel) {
        adapter = (UserAdapter)((CachedUserModel)user).getDelegateForUpdate();
    } else {
        adapter = (UserAdapter)user;
    }
    return adapter;
}

public void setModel(ComponentModel model) {
    this.model = model;`enter code here`
}

public void setSession(KeycloakSession session) {
    this.session = session;
}
```

I deploy the jar into keycloak wildfly server with no problem it recognize my new adapter in the option user federation but when i try to list the users i get this error:

> 17:56:40,460 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@762c7243[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@2b300f6c connection handles=0 lastReturned=1565819800458 lastValidated=1565819732106 lastCheckedOut=1565819800454 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@e92a386 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@4743ffe9[pool=userDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@3e8f3c8b[connectionListener=762c7243 connectionManager=2c5ddfb5 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/userDS] txSync=null]
>   17:56:40,470 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component UserStorageProvider for method public java.util.List org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider.searchForUser(java.util.Map,org.keycloak.models.RealmModel,int,int): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:203)
>   org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider$$$view1.searchForUser(Unknown Source)
>       at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$searchForUser$2(UserStorageManager.java:556)
>       at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.query(UserStorageManager.java:505)
>       at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.searchForUser(UserStorageManager.java:554)
>       at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.searchForUser(UserCacheSession.java:583)
>       at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.searchForUser(UsersResource.java:247)
>       at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.getUsers(UsersResource.java:220)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
>       at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
>       at org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider.getUserModels(UserStorageProvider.java:182)
>       at org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider.searchForUser(UserStorageProvider.java:172)
>       at org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider.searchForUser(UserStorageProvider.java:165)
>       at org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider.searchForUser(UserStorageProvider.java:197)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1507)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
>       ... 138 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@762c7243[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@2b300f6c connection handles=0 lastReturned=1565819800458 lastValidated=1565819732106 lastCheckedOut=1565819800454 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@e92a386 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@4743ffe9[pool=userDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@3e8f3c8b[connectionListener=762c7243 connectionManager=2c5ddfb5 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/userDS] txSync=null]
>       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
>       at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
>       at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
>       ... 158 more
>   Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@762c7243[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@2b300f6c connection handles=0 lastReturned=1565819800458 lastValidated=1565819732106 lastCheckedOut=1565819800454 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@e92a386 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@4743ffe9[pool=userDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@3e8f3c8b[connectionListener=762c7243 connectionManager=2c5ddfb5 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/userDS] txSync=null]
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:1055)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:792)
>       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
>       ... 162 more
>   Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000461: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:571)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:977)
>       ... 164 more
>   Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: Error enlisting resource in transaction=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:-2c55aa43:5d54831c:2d7 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.checkEnlisted(TxConnectionListener.java:956)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:394)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:564)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Failed to enlist
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:1000)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:379)
>       ... 166 more
>
> 17:56:40,476 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-2) Uncaught server error: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:203)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:364)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
>       org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.query(UserStorageManager.java:505)
>       at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.searchForUser(UserStorageManager.java:554)
>       at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.searchForUser(UserCacheSession.java:583)
>       at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.searchForUser(UsersResource.java:247)
>   Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@762c7243[state=DESTROYED managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@2b300f6c connection handles=0 lastReturned=1565819800458 lastValidated=1565819732106 lastCheckedOut=1565819800454 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@e92a386 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@4743ffe9[pool=userDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@3e8f3c8b[connectionListener=762c7243 connectionManager=2c5ddfb5 warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/userDS] txSync=null]
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:1055)
>   Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Failed to enlist
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:1000)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:379)
>
> 17:56:40,480 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component UserStorageProvider for method public void org.keycloak.provider.UserStorageProvider.close(): javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: WFLYEJB0168: Could not find EJB with id UUIDSessionID [4a1304ec-ca2f-4cbf-8de2-846bcc0d9892]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:55)